# Which linux device driver is responsible for formatting and writing root file system?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, imx6

I'm getting started with imx6 processors and the procedure involved to bring up the board is to flash u-boot kernel dtb and rootfs which is taken care of by mfg tools provided by nxp.
 For creating a rootfs partition the command run is

```
mkfs.ext3 -F -E nodiscard /dev/mmcblk1p2
```

and for untaring the rootfs into this partition it is.

```
pipe tar -jxv -C /mnt/mmcblk1p2
```

I'd like to know the working of this, which kernel driver is being called for executing these commands?
My kernel version is 4.9.88.
I did find a few driver files related to mmc in the path

```
/drivers/mmc/core
```

but there is nothing related to filesystem reading or writing here. 
Can anyone explain which driver files are used to create filesystems?

Answer (score 1):

Creating the filesystem is done by the *userspace* program `mke2fs` (of which `mkfs.ext3` is an alias) which is part of the [e2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/) package. The kernel and drivers have no way of *creating* filesystems. Therefore, only the block driver for accessing the MMC device is involved, but no file system driver.